# Как контролировать кеширование ответа php

Tags: php, кэширование, cache-control

Браузеры, вебсервера, прокси и кеширующие сервера при принятии решения кешировать или нет полученный контент следуют http заголовкам ответа Cache-Control, Expire, Pragma, Last-Modified, Vary и т.д.

Встала необходимость кеширования динамического контента возвращаемого PHP. Как оказалось PHP по-умолчанию устанавливает эти заголовки в  значения, запрещающие кешировать контент на любом уровне:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: дата из прошлого
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store
```

Как настроить правильные заголовки чтобы эффективно управлять кешированием?

Comment: написал чуть более развернуто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Глобально управлять режимом кеширования** можно установив в php.ini опцию [session.cache_limiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter) = **public**. Дефолтное значение: no-cache. Время жизни кэша можно установить в опции [session.cache_expire](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire).

Для целей получения / установки этих опций можно использовать функции: *session_cache_limiter()* и *session_cache_expire()*.

При установке этих опций PHP будет устанавливать соответствующие http заголовки ответа: *Cache-Control, Expire, Pragma, Last-Modified*.

Можно **отключить** глобальное кеширование установив `session.cache_limiter = ""` и гибко управлять кешированием отправляя указанные заголовки http ответа из Вашего приложения.

Например:

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=900, stale-while-revalidate=5');
```